# What is the strategy of android os to determine to call gc ?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

```
public static class GoBack {
    public static Stack<Bundle> goBackStack;
｝
```

In my android app,i write a class which parent is Application,I declare an inner class as the code above.

My question is , After my app run in backgroud for a long time and then come back to the app,the goBackStack is always null . I don't know why? And how can I avoid it?

Comment: Just do not develop application, until you read basics, and problem will dissapear :)

Comment: goBackStack is publicly available. check anywhrer it is not modified to null

Comment: I'm sure goBackStack is not modified to null.

Answer (score 1):

Your `goBackStack` becomes null as soon, as Android decides to kill your application. Since this variable is initialized somewhere else, it's still null after relaunch of your app (because it's not initialized on second time).

Solution is simple - do not think about static variables as they are persistent storage. They are not. Use `SharedPreferences`, `SQLite` database or file system instead.

Comment: thanks for your advicement. I handle it by checking whether it is null when i use it . If is null , then I will initialize it again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your entire process is eventually killed. The garbage collector will not collect objects that are statically referenced.

Look at re-initialising your data or making use of `onSavedInstanceState`. Alternatively you can look at using a database or `SharedPreferences` to persist the data.

Comment: Since the entire app is killed.Then how can the function onSavedInstanceState be called?